# @postgres - looking for help

Tags: linux

I need to do a few tasks:

I'm using CentOS 6.7 via Oracle VM Virtual Box

1. Find project with name = PROJECT_NAME (table: Project; columns: name)
2. List projects where id is PROJECT_ID1 or PROJECT_ID2 (table: Project; columns: id) (use "id in (...)" and not "or/=")
3. List id and name of projects where id > 10 (table: Projects; columns: id, name)
4. List id, start date and name of projects sorted by start date (table: Projects; columns: id, startdate, name; use: ORDER BY .. ASC)
5. List id, name of projects with id > 10 and name = PROJECT_NAME (table: Projects; columns: id, name; use: AND operation)
6. List id of projects and limit results to last 5 (table: Project, columns: id, use: LIMIT operation)
7. List last 5 started  projects (table: Project, columns: startdate, use: ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT)
8. List projects started later than 2013-03-03 00:00:00 (table: Project, columns: startdate; use: startdate < '2013-03-03 00:00:00')
9. List users with username containing word 'test' (table: PMUser; columns: username; use: username like '%test%')
10. List users with username containing word 'test' at the end (table: PMUser; columns: username; use: username like '%test')
11. List number of users (table: PMUser; columns: *; use: count(*))
12. Find maximum user id (table: PMUser; columns: id; use: max(id))

EDIT SOLUTION:

My Task solutions:
1. `SELECT name FROM Project WHERE name = 'PROJECT_NAME';`
2. `SELECT id FROM Project WHERE id in (4214, 5020);` (not sure about this one, but looks like PROJECT_ID1 is just numbers I need to type, still need some solution/answer to this)
3. `SELECT id,name FROM Project WHERE id > 10;`
4. `SELECT id,startdate,name FROM Project ORDER BY startdate ASC;`
5. `SELECT id,name FROM Project WHERE id > 10 AND name = 'PROJECT_NAME';`
6. `SELECT id FROM Project LIMIT 5;`
7. `SELECT startdate FROM Project ORDER BY startdate DESC LIMIT 5;`
8. `SELECT startdate FROM Project WHERE startdate <'2013-03-03 00:00:00';`
9. `SELECT username FROM PMUser wHERE username like '%test%`;'
10.`SELECT username FROM PMUser WHERE username like '%test';`
11. `SELECT count(*) FROM PMUser;`
12. `SELECT max(id) FROM PMuser;`

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Well actually I need it to get job, I had a lot of more to do and "ONLY" this part is unsolved. Well, I've no idea how to start it... one things that seems to be working was \d PROJECT_NAME, but can't find out how to set (table: Project; columns: name).          @taliezin any hint where should I look for then?

Comment: centOS 6.7 without GUI? only terminal?

Comment: @lese Yes, only terminal without GUI. I'd be very greatfull for ANY help, simply don't know how to start any of these.

Comment: @Michał: The keywords you should search for are "SQL tutorial". So you can tell when you find a useful document, the answer to your first question should be something similar to `SELECT * FROM Project WHERE name = 'PROJECT_NAME'`.

Comment: @Dhag really thanks for this, also I'd like to apologize for my stupid brain, but when I enter this, I get nothing

Comment: what's the output if you type `\conninfo`

Comment: "You are connected to database "test" as user "test" on host "127.0.0.1" at port "5432"." I've forgot to add, that I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager

Comment: `\dt` check if the tables interest you are inside this database called "test"

Comment: Yes they're in test database

Comment: As I'm going to task two "List projects where id is PROJECT_ID1 or PROJECT_ID2 (table: Project; columns: id) (use "id in (...)" and not "or/=")" am I doing it correct - "SELECT ID FROM PROJECT WHERE ID IN (1, 2);" ? I'm not sure with WHERE part

Answer (score 3):

The core of your task/exercise seems to be SQL queries. I'm not going to help with them. But just a shove to make you start with psql cli : )

Following the commands I frequently use:

```
# launch psql
psql -U <username> <database>

# list all databases
## here you will find the one they prepared for you
\l

# change database
\c <database_name>

# show tables
\dt

# describe table (show columns)
\d+ <table_name>
```

---

to find other psql commands you can type the following from inside the psql cli:

```
\?
```

From here on you can begin to use just SQL to solve the task. **Note** that all the points require a SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I saw this already but still can't understand how to solve any of my tasks. I'll keep trying.

Comment: you say you can't understand how to solve any of your tasks, but a good starting point is been provided by **dhag** already. Use that query and you are done with point 1. I think you just tired after all the rest of the work you have done. Don't surrender!

Comment: I've tried something like: "SELECT table:Project, columns:name FROM PROJECT_NAME", but nothing happen when i enter this. Same for dhag ansewer lines. I'm working on this since 9 hours so I may be a little tired, time is not working in my favor.

Comment: you are using the wrong syntax, if you give a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) you will see that the statement is always as follow `SELECT <columns> FROM <table>`

Comment: OK I THINK I UNDERSTAND (sorry for caps, brain exploded), to make it works I forgot to add ";" in the end of statement. So please correct me in first task which is: "Find project with name = PROJECT_NAME (table: Project; columns: name)", I should simply use "SELECT NAME FROM PROJECT;", is it correct?

Comment: the query you mentioned will return all the rows of project table. you need to add the `where` clause in order to filter the records to obtain what you want. `select name from project where name='PROJECT_NAME'` and you are right! don't forget `;`

Comment: Ok so the key for my problem was ";" I'll do my best to find out how to solve other tasks, thank you very much.